# How do you pronounce Edward Liveing?

Tags: pronunciation

Not sure if it's kosher to ask this here -- I was reading about Oliver Sacks and came across the name of a 19th century migraine expert he was inspired by, Edward Liveing.  How do you pronounce Liveing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Dr. Sacks](http://www.webofstories.com/play/oliver.sacks/359) (at 0:58), it's pronounced just as you would think: /laɪvɪŋ/, to rhyme with "driving" (not with "living").